# How to use conditional to define a icon color in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, conditional-statements

I would like that when a variable is = true the icon would be a color, but if it was = false it would be another.Any idea how I can do that in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not specified, I'm going to use the container widget as an example.

```
bool colorChange = false;
Container(
 color: colorChange? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
  
)
```

This will work for sure.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
 Icon(
      Icons.widgets,
      color: (your boolean value goes here)? Colors.blue : Colors.amber,
 ),
```